# How to declare virtual path in .wxs file?

Tags: wix, setup-project

I am quite new in creating setup project using .wxs file.I am using WIX 3.9. I want to change the physical path to virtual path in .wxs file. 
Currently .wsx file is using physical path like this -

```
<Component Id="cmp2CB74B07C01493F593A258BAE09C0B1C" Guid="08CD4620-DE67-4C7A-A97A-212AB5BA5E52">
  <File Id="filCF6108D60D7B1865907043E2ABFE30DF" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\ProjectName\Client\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" />
</Component>
```

I want to use virtual path something like this -

```
  <Component Id="cmp2CB74B07C01493F593A258BAE09C0B1C" Guid="08CD4620-DE67-4C7A-A97A-212AB5BA5E52">
    <File Id="filCF6108D60D7B1865907043E2ABFE30DF" KeyPath="yes" Source="~\ProjectName\Client\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" />
    </Component>
```

How could I do this in .wxs file? Please suggest.

Comment: "Virtual path" might not be the best terminology to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are already using heat to generate your components, you can specify a variable by using `-var <VariableName>`. According to the [docs](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) this will:

> Substitute File/@Source="SourceDir" with a preprocessor or a wix variable (e.g. -var var.MySource will become File/@Source="$(var.MySource)\myfile.txt" and -var wix.MySource will become File/@Source="!(wix.MySource)\myfile.txt".

I use this by running the heat command in the post-build event of the original project, and passing in `-var var.$(ProjectName).TargetDir`. The resulting `File` will have `Source="$(var.ProjectName.TargetDir)\whatever.dll"`. As long as `ProjectName` is added as a reference to the wix setup project then the variable will be resolved properly.